# Loop through string until it reaches a specific character

Tags: string, for-loop, while-loop, substring

I am trying to increment an integer by 1 every-time the letter in a string isn't equal to the specific character (e.g. **a**),

For example a string of **dfla**, would count 3. Because the loop will break at 'a'.

How would I able to do this?

```
private int countToFirstCharacter(String name, String character) {

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < materialName.length(); i++) {

        //Increment count if it isn't equal to a, then break loop.
        //Stuck here.

    }

    return count;

}
```

Comment: This is Java (Object Orientated)

Comment: Why you get materialName.Length instread of name.Length?

Comment: See my update in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No Need to a loop:

```
string s = "dfla";
int x = s.IndexOf("a"); // It will show you 3
```

Another solution can be:

```
private static int countToFirstCharacter(String name, char character)
{

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
    {
        if (name[i].Equals(character))
            break;
        else
            count++;
    }

    return count;

}
```

Comment: Would this still get the first index of the first a if there is more than one a in the string?

Comment: @user3613680 Yes, it will.

Comment: The problem is: "I am trying to increment an integer by 1 every-time the letter in a string isn't equal to the specific character". Your solution gives the number of characters until the 1st occurence

Comment: Perhaps I should just wait for @user3613680 to say whether the purpose is to find the 1st occurrence, or the count of all characters but the input character. Sorry

Answer (score -1):

Replace all occurences of the character with an empty character, and then check the length of the string

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char), char)
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29)

Comment: How exactly does any of this help address the OP's issue?

Comment: Could you tell me what OP is?

Comment: OP = "original poster"; forum-speak for the originator of a thread.